# how to send an unsubscribe link with an unique id to the recipients with phpmailer

Tags: php, foreach, phpmailer, unsubscribe

I am using phpmailer to send a newsletter to some subscribers. Each subscriber is part of a "Category". Before sending, i first choose the category which the subscribers belong. Each user has a unique id called `$recipients_id` .
What happens: In the code below, each user gets all the "unscribe links"; so also of the other members. And he/she should only receive the unsubscribe with his/her own id:

```
// part of the script
$mail->IsHTML(true);                            //Sets message type to HTML             
$mail->Subject = "Newsletter";                  //Sets the Subject of the message
$mail->Body = $_POST["message"];
foreach($category_matches as $file) { // grab subscribers of the category
    // get data out of txt file     
    $lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // set lines from matched file into an array
    $recipients_id = $lines[0]; //  id of recipients
    $recipients_name = $lines[2]; //  name of recipients
    $recipients_email = $lines[3]; //  email of the recipients                                  
    $mail->AddBCC($recipients_email, $recipients_name); //bcc to all subscribers of the category
    $mail->Body .= '<a href="http://example.com/newsletter/unsubscribe.php?id='.$recipients_id.'">Unsubscribe</a>'; //unsubscribe anchor    

    echo $recipients_id.'<br />'; // this echos me the id's of the subscribers in the category to check only 


}

if($mail->Send())           //Send an Email. Return true on success or false on error
{
    $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Newsletter sent to subscribers of:<b> '.$recipients_category.'</b></div>';
}
else
{
    $result = 'div class="alert alert-danger">There is an Error</div>';
}
```

Comment: You can't do that if you add all recipients as BCC for the same email since they all will get just that, the same email. If you want the content to be different for each user, you need to send them one by one and update the content (in this case the link) for each user.

Comment: What Magnus said, and also take a look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) for how to send to a list efficiently.

Comment: Good explanation and solution @Magnus Eriksson  and Synchro for this problem. Thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comments above, your code should be something like this:

```
// part of the script
$mail->IsHTML(true);                            //Sets message type to HTML             
$mail->Subject = "Newsletter";                  //Sets the Subject of the message
foreach($category_matches as $file) { // grab subscribers of the category
    // get data out of txt file     
    $lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // set lines from matched file into an array
    $recipients_id = $lines[0]; //  name of recipients
    $recipients_name = $lines[2]; //  name of recipients
    $recipients_email = $lines[3]; //  email of the recipients                              
    $mail->AddAddress($recipients_email, $recipients_name);     //Adds a "To" address

    try {
        $mail->Body = $_POST["message"].'<br /><br />'.'<a href="http://example.com/newsletter/unsubscribe.php?id='.$recipients_id.'">Unsubscribe</a>'; //unsubscribe anchor
        $mail->Send();  
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Newsletter sent to subscribers of:<b> '.$recipients_category.'</b></div>';                  

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Mailer Error (' . htmlspecialchars($recipients_email) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '</div>';
        $mail->smtp->reset(); // reset SMTP connection
    }

    $mail->clearAddresses(); // Clear all addresses for the next iteration

}
```

NOTE: there is only 1 `$mail->Body`, which includes the message and the unique_id link for unsubscribing.
Bind the echo's to a var `$result` and echo `$result` outside the loop; otherwise you will get them several times, for each recipient you send